# AWS Amplify Storage not working as expected on all AWS Cognito Users

Tags: aws-amplify-cli

I just started using AWS Amplify not long ago and I've encountered this problem.

Initially, I have a cognito user(user_1) registered under AWS Amplify Auth. Whenever I logged in to **user_1** and perform Storage.get, it worked perfectly fine.

Then, I kept getting 'NoSuchKey' and 404 (Not Found) errors after performing Storage.get using **user_2**, a newly registered user under AWS Amplify Auth.

This is the comparison of the actual s3 file url and the error url.

ACTUAL URL: https://sebuzaef1cdade409a4bde9b505f7fcaac1473201533-test.s3.amazonaws.com/protected/us-east-1%3Ad17df1e4-2e35-41d8-81e9-c4e4d00fd9ed/High_Quality_Fitness_Gym_Wrist_Glove.jpg

ERROR URL: https://sebuzaef1cdade409a4bde9b505f7fcaac1473201533-test.s3.amazonaws.com/protected/us-east-1%3A808ec3d3-e9e6-4327-955a-3c8861fd943c/High_Quality_Fitness_Gym_Wrist_Glove.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAS3JVEOYBE4IS2Q63%2F20200902%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200902T095409Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJL%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIGGKLG4peZZ0%2BcnpCCz6vFjB8n01vWBI7fL9OgJ1c1b9AiBdVT%2BJB%2BnK%2FQV1QCl28SKv8SpC%2BWQjmxYTZV%2BnbuL7xiqZBgiL%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAEaDDE5NjA2OTMyNDI5MCIM3McHCZICFe14O%2BWsKu0FDMgcLvU7P%2BQERl4cPm0B82T4qb0Ds01kHF3BFJCCNaHD9BJLTAHXdHeXPJA9VKlExJ0eETFmZKcBV9VY2A5Mwy4OGxHwmBmkq%2B3EavGzCGw77cy%2BAPu%2FK3Yauf5x9OJwyA6%2FXp9wEhyn9YKcw0j8NpTpzc1ysSJ2uDM1wFXi4nwQ0J4FsbE88%2Fatu9JbbRWoZqfZr7yOiSF71QuEX5fVfXgp%2FUv19dC5mAeUxR05gfJIM5ImjzzA8RZpkNE7yoRA4H1bY11UxuBXmvaw%2FROmG688YTz7uCozSMSp5mYl4qRQAqh3wsuO9yrCHebhqHOPuyTVxZ6IZXSuj8oXvZGIJX3%2F1d4KsEj3TSHAFYSU1wQKIq6xojanQOM30iGvV9ZxjSvc32uUmmYiDR%2FU7tnvLFg0Pi2wT6oL%2BlspVN3qXtAHXfk4SvXE4rzbKOnCzXUDEI%2Bs9LdiylW6JNCF7lgl6egd1aPwDDmf7BC2kj%2BwO8EmLa41syGtBBodSYZt65KtbXiLb1ojK%2BAa39%2BKQYR0pxlOiHM%2B6egqYY7h2IzkZnIvZIWiRHlnLsgo5tX3cXwOBWFSfsyBpomEu0x2Ic0OGcQPLhzad1ebt0ngtMPwX7Xr%2FKcI%2BA%2FZL8KmD%2Bl14Hman1DnMK1UgKTtPAyM7%2F3QbZtG3srIs0Ud%2BEKxBjJz1iP5AEOmGeh1Deqwp8kGN49azR7GfECIcgn8WSYBKBr%2FIjQzL0hWHAoiEX1DqB4LEdVe6%2FvKsrBnn0nkPwXmOBtMx%2BLC%2BTzEdrFnbtyEoKPIYbkHwiwlOjyZif1yUETSu2Mx0kCqcJBa3IlQcrhct%2FYv2m3P9xu8GNApMUHuo0lx75J1hAfz%2FGkoQKawX6jfuULFsKAfUx9l3zoKcdaZqwV9kv5dczPpS%2FytnkE%2Fm2J3e3z9Ff%2FQmp7VtagbaPCi7F3TCn0mWyAzeW5tPKsInLK%2BfHatk7YDCrkwPLH2dcWsKi%2B9toRFcohmwa7WUGUwwde9%2BgU6iALvAbruuk1EaEmSwHhZwf3xf1DG9FXR88neggymAJHU9AhjpshjG3AdtXBTPLvMurOJZ3saG2rQFhmA5vjXJu2TOT6Elz9sctViI5rvX1XwIRxrlZX5eD7ICbISRGIP2N4U4TfJV%2BxU1Pl7WtFth4k0wiu5SP8KETKrzF24kUFzL7eS%2FkFDzwqebObQA63A8eKxl%2FS4%2F3KGYT%2Bd0BBe9hhNd2tTr%2FkSrcrEVBeX%2B2rD%2B%2FJuBK1QmqLXO%2FBcFGRgBi5wCiSgBuWI%2FGLg4Pc3d9WV%2BgPsF0gmTVFQt%2FwJiCb3d%2FAGCDSxTO%2FMij%2BM%2FNmO1wsrbJa6QouGrARE38j%2FT%2FvFzvSeOZVJFj8%3D&X-Amz-Signature=0ddd882410d0d3dc77b92efa9c64b699001f83d6796d9702d4a979561a6d2a31&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I think this URLs are irrelevant and cannot be accessed by public.

Comment: While installing storage, can you try with  'Authenticated & Guest users'